# What is KSC's HURCON II?

Tags: nasa, safety, weather

HURCON II sounds like `DEFCON 2`, the *2nd highest level* of five levels of [The DEFense readiness CONdition (DEFCON); an alert state used by the United States Armed Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFCON).

> The DEFCON system was developed by the [Joint Chiefs of Staff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Chiefs_of_Staff) (JCS) and [unified and specified combatant commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Combatant_Command). It prescribes five graduated levels of readiness (or states of alert) for the U.S. military. It increases in severity from DEFCON 5 (least severe) to DEFCON 1 (most severe) to match varying military situations.

**Question:** Does the Kennedy Space Center have formal levels of readiness for hurricanes that match the DEFCON's 5 down to 1 escalation, or is that a bit of humor mixed with the very serious message?

NPR's [Riding Out Irma On Florida's Space Coast — And Keeping On Eye On The Spacecraft](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/09/10/550003276/riding-out-irma-on-floridas-space-coast-and-keeping-on-eye-on-the-spacecraft) is worth a quick read.

---

**below:** "NASA's Kennedy Space Center, shown on Saturday, closed ahead of the arrival of Hurricane Irma as a crew of 120 arrived to ride out the storm." From [NPR](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/09/10/550003276/riding-out-irma-on-floridas-space-coast-and-keeping-on-eye-on-the-spacecraft).
Bruce Weaver/AFP/Getty Images

[image]

**below:** DEFCON levels, with 1 being the highest level of alert. From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dc_all_five.svg).

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[HURCON levels range from I to V and are properly defined by the USAF.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HURCON)

The KSC uses these levels as well, as outlined by the ["KENNEDY SPACE CENTER
AND CAPE CANAVERAL AIR FORCE STATION CONSOLIDATED COMPREHENSIVE EMERGENCY MANAGEMENT PLAN (CCEMP)"](https://prod.nais.nasa.gov/eps/eps_data/128659-SOL-001-011.pdf).

The plan establishes that both the space center and air force base are subject to very similar threats and presents a joint plan to combat them.

> The CCEMP combines NASA and CCAFS requirements into a single document.  [...] The CCEMP applies to all NASA and CCAFS contractor and subcontractor
>   organizations, USAF, and NASA personnel and other Federal agencies and contractors operating within the boundaries of CCAFS and KSC.

Hurricanes are identified as a major threat to both bases in Section 4 of the Executive summary.

Section 4.D of the Plan deals with mitigation of Hurricanes (page 27). 4.D (2) reads:

> The KSC Director and the 45th Space Wing Commander will jointly establish the
>   hurricane condition (HURCON) **applicable to the Spaceport and the Florida Annexes** to maximum extent possible.

(Highlight mine).

HURCON is applied to the spaceport.

[Patrick AFB offers a "Hurricane Survival Guide" outlining the HURCON levels as of 2018](https://www.patrick.af.mil/Portals/14/documents/45SW%20Hurricane%20Survival%20Guide%20(Apr%202018).pdf?ver=2018-05-22-170835-280):

> **Hurricane Conditions (HURCONs).**
>   A tool utilized by 45th Space Wing to ensure pre-disaster information and actions are disseminated and implemented throughout the installations. These conditions provide sufficient preparation time to safeguard personnel, aircraft, equipment, and facilities. HURCONs are based upon forecast on-set of destructive winds 58 mph (50 kts) or more at a specific time. The timeframes listed below are defined in AFMAN 10-2504, Air Force Incident Management Guidance for Major Accidents and Natural Disasters, and 45th Space Wing Installation Emergency Management Plan (IEMP) 10-2. The 45th Space Wing Command or designated representative declares HURCONs as appropriate. HURCONs descend from HURCON 5 to HURCON 1.

The tables on page 4 & 5 provide further information on the conditions and activities:

[image: HURCON levels]

[image: HURCON activities]

Comment: According to nasaspaceflight.com's Sep 8 article, Cape Canaveral Air Force Station recognizes a HURCON V, but I don't know if this is a reliable source.

Comment: Yeah, I know that article, but it doesn#t have any sources and the CCEMp I linked above is from 2000, so there might have been some changes. I do not have L2 access, sadly, but supposedly some material can be found there.

Comment: @OrganicMarble according to Wikipedia's [HURCON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HURCON) the level of alert escalates as the numbers descend, in analogy with  DEFCON and FPCON, so I'm not sure what V would be, perhaps https://youtu.be/L3HQMbQAWRc ?

Comment: @uhoh CCAFS has HURCOn V, but KSC has not. But I couldn't find any more information other then "For the CCAFS, HURCON V begins 96 hours (4 days) prior to the arrival of 58 mph (50 knot) sustained winds." (see the linked article).

Answer (score 7):

Just FYI, Johnson Space Center also has hurricane readiness levels.  But, because no 2 NASA centers can do anything the same, they use a different system.

> #### Level 5 - Awareness
>
> Hurricane and tropical storm preparation is a continuing activity.  There should be a heightened state of awareness before and during hurricane season.
>
> […]
>
> #### Level 4 - Concern
>
> JSC will initiate Level 4 activities when a **storm poses a threat to JSC within 72 hours or a storm enters the Gulf of Mexico**.
>
> […]
>
> #### Level 3 - Preparation
>
> Level 3 activities prepare JSC to be in a position to be able to close down operations in a timely and orderly manner if necessary by notifying and 
>   assembling the appropriate personnel and groups.
>   The Director, Center Operations (JA) will authorize 
>   Level 3 activities when there is a chance that a **severe weather condition will pose a significant threat to the Center within 48 hours**.
>
> […]
>
> #### Level 2 - Center Closure
>
> Level 2 activities consist of completing all protective measures that will place the Center in a final state of preparedness.
>   Upon authorization by the Center Director, the Director of Center Operations will start Level 2 Activities to the HIMT when there is a possibility that a 
>   **severe weather condition will pose a significant threat to the Center within 36 hours**.
>
> […]
>
> #### Level 1 Rideout, Assessment, and Recovery (post-storm) Activities
>
> JSC will start Level 1 activities on authorization by the Center Director when severe weather conditions poses an imminent threat to the Center 
>   within 24 hours.
>   Activities during the storm period will be limited to:
>
> - HIMT activities.
> - Essential emergency repairs only if they can be done without endangering the health and safety of assigned employees.
>
> Activities after the storm:
>
> - The HIMT assessing storm damage and arranging for necessary repairs on a 
>     priority basis.
> - Recovery operations initiated by the Director, Center Operations.

I *think* HIMT is Hurricane Impact Management Team.

Source: [JSC S&MA Hurricane Checklist](https://jschandbook.jsc.nasa.gov/sma_hurricane_prep/docs/Hurricane_Checklist_MGT.pdf)

Comment: Well, the timetables are similar, except KSC has HURCON II at 24h not 36h, and HURCON I at 12h not 24h. HIMT at JSC seems to correspond to HMT at KSC.